# Computing CPU utilization with ps, awk, and sysctl

Tags: bash, shell, awk

In my tmux config, I like to display some basic stats (CPU usage, memory usage, etc) in the status bar at the bottom. To compute the CPU usage, I was previously doing the following:

```
cpuusage=$(ps -Ao pcpu | awk '{sum = sum + $1}END{printf "%4.1f", sum}')
```

This worked on my old Ubuntu laptop, where the value of `$cpuusage` ranged from `0.0` to `100.0`. But moving over to my Mac I started getting CPU usage values like `113.7` or `239.8` -- well above the maximum `100.0` I would expect. The answer was pretty quickly obvious: it's giving the utilization of a single core, and this machine has 12 cores.

To correct this, I wanted to divide by the number of cores. To get the number of cores I used `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`. On my Mac this returns `12`. I then tried to divide like so:

```
cpupercent=$(($cpuusage/$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)))
```

So long as `cpuusage` was an integer divisible by 12, this worked (e.g. when `$cpuusage` was exactly `60`, this returned `5`) however whenever the usage was not divisible by 12 this simply returned an empty string.

I suspect the issue is that `$cpuusage` is a string and not an integer or a float (and upon doing some basic research I've determined that Bash doesn't actually support floats), but I'm not sure how I should be solving this.

Should I spin up a second `awk` process and pass in both the cpu usage and the number of CPUs, like so?

```
cpupercent=$(awk '{printf "%4.1f", $1 / $2}' <<< $cpuusage $(sysctl -n hw.ncpu))
```

Or is there a way to pass the number of CPUs directly into the first `awk` process?

```
cpupercent=$(ps - Ao pcpu | <insert num CPU> | awk '{sum = sum + $1}END{printf "%4.1f", sum / $2}')
```

Or is there some other tool I should be using for this job, like `bc`?

Comment: Though you have provided details in your post but still it will be better to understand your post if you can post values of `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`, `cpuusage ` etc in your post so it will be helpful  for people to guide, since all may not be having mac o.s with them(like me).

Comment: I've updated my question slightly. I already gave several examples of the value of `$cpuusage`, which changes from second to second but is generally a string such as `83.1`. But I've now included the output of `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`, which prints `12` on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question raises two points: (1) source of load (2) source of CPU count

(1) source of load

- Use current calculation (sum of ps). However note this will (almost) always underestimate the current load, as ps `%cpu` is calculate for each task, based on the task starting point. - see man ps '%cpu' for details.
- Read from the /proc the system "official" load average (cat /proc/loadavg)
- Use a utility that extract the data: uptime, top -n1, etc.

I suggest using cat /proc/loadavg

(2) source of CPU count

Already solved & discussed in the answer/comments.

(3) Division

Either 'awk', or 'bc', or bash (using scaled) can be used to perform floating point. Assuming load, ncpu calculate before:

- bc: use: 
  `pct=$(echo "scale=1; $load/$ncpu" | bc)`
- awk: use 
  `pct=$(awk 'END { printf "%.1f\n", (0+0+iload)/ncpu}' iload=$load ncpu=$ncpu /dev/null )`
- Pure Bash: Not recommended - clumsy: 
  `V=$((load*100/ncpu)) ; pct=${V:0:2}.${V: -2}`

Of the above, I prefer the bc - simpler, easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: I can use `cat /proc/loadavg` on *nix machines, but unfortunately the whole `/proc` directory doesn't exist on Mac OS X / Darwin machines. I also tried `top -n1` and it didn't work on Mac. Although `uptime` did give three numbers: `1.67 1.84 1.88` - not sure how to read that yet, but I assume one is what I want

Comment: I just gave this a try, using the `bc` solution. I left my current method for computing load since `/proc` and `top` didn't work on Mac, and when I google'd `uptime` it seemed like it was a different thing all together (not CPU usage). But instead of trying to find a one-liner I wrote three lines: one to compute `$load`, one to compute `$ncpu`, and then the `bc` line you suggested to combine them. Worked like a charm. I also piped the result to `awk` to format it how I wanted, since `.1` doesn't look as nice as `0.1%`

Comment: @stevendesu  The uptime 3 numbers are the same as the /proc/loadavg. They represent the load for the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When I googled it the article I found said that the "load" in the `uptime` command refers to how many processes are utilizing the CPU (e.g. if 5 processes are using the CPU, the "load" is 5) and not the actual percentage utilization. So I'm sticking with my `ps` solution for now, as that gives me a value based on percentage utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `iostat -c` combination with `awk` to get the current CPU utilization.

```
iostat -c|awk 'awk '/[[:digit:]]$/{print 100-$NF}''
```

The output is between `0-100`

#### Sample output

```
7.95
```

#### Explanation

`iostat -c` provide some statistics about current CPU utilization:

```
Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 (psdbperf)  10/28/2019      _x86_64_        (32 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.68    0.00    0.13    0.32    0.00   98.87
```

The `awk` script:

```
/[[:digit:]]$/ { # if current line ends with a digit
   print (100-$NF) # print 100 - %idle
}
```